Low FPS on high-end hardware running my graphics renderer using VulkanSDK
Experiencing very low frame rate for a simple graphics renderer with high-end hardware. Struggling to go beyond 200 FPS with any power settings cranked up for performance.
Coming from Windows11 where FPS would normally sit around 1000-1500FPS in debug/development builds.
Tried multiple NVIDIA drivers.
Using NVIDIA prop. Driver Version: 550.107.02
CPU R9 5900x
GPU RTX 3080
RAM 32GB RAM
Using NVME SSD
Ubuntu 24.04

Only chance is to use the driver, that has been compiled against your kernel. Besides I would try to log in with XSession and not wayland (which is the default)

Thanks for the answer. I managed to solve the issue. Problem was selecting correct physical device/GPU during Vulkan initialization, as it would default to 'llvmpipe' and not the discrete GPU. Not an Ubuntu issue specifically, but rather poor code maintenance.

Sounds like you fixed it. At the bottom of the question is the answer your own question option. Would be best if your comment was there as an answer so that others can read it in the future.
